# How should I punctuate the "Shocked" line from Casablanca?

Tags: punctuation

I'm writing something that mimics the famous "Shocked" line from Casablanca, but I can't find a good way to punctuate the phrase without it looking odd. Any ideas please?

> I'm shocked, shocked, that StackExchange would answer my question.

That just looks like I'm listing all my reactions.

Comment: You only need the first comma. The second is apparently incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

> I'm shocked ─ shocked! ─ that StackExchange would answer my question.

Comment: Now, let's not pussyfoot around with Captain's Renault's feigned sense of shock! Someone at Rick's had definitely nobbled the roulette wheel in his favor, what?